# WPF: Text rotation and alignment issues

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a label for a WPF project which involves sections being of different foreground colours and a special character that has to undergo a 180 rotation. I am nearly there but there are a few problems.

Here is the image so far:

[image]

and here is the XAML that generates it:

```
       <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel Margin="5"
                    Background="White"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Text="XXX" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       FontSize="50"
                       Foreground="Green"
                       Text="Δ">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Foreground="Orange"
                       Text="YYY" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
```

The problem with this is that the bottom 'special character' between the 'XXX' and 'YYY' that has been rotated 180 is not aligned with the bottoms of 'XXX' and 'YYY'.

So, I tried to rework the XAML where I had one `TextBlock` and each section was controlled as a `Run`.

Here is an image of this:

[image]

And here is the XAML for the revised image:

```
       <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel Margin="5"
                    Background="White"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Run Foreground="Black" Text="XXX" />
                <Run FontSize="50"
                     Foreground="Green"
                     Text="Δ">
                    <!-- <Run.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                    </Run.LayoutTransform> -->
                </Run>
                <Run Foreground="Orange" Text="YYY" />
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
```

As you will notice that while the bottom alignment problem is now ok,  this is worse than the first attempt as there are now gaps between the special character and the 'XXX' and 'YYY'. And a `Run` does not support transformations.

So, how can I achieve this? That is, create the first image but with the special character vertically aligned with the 'XXX' and 'YYY'.

Comment: Why don't you simply draw triangle yourself? The text rendering is tricky. Rotate single character and allign it is a bad idea, unless you do drawing yourself (means you will take care to measure and position everything).

Comment: @Sinatr thanks for the comment. but I am keen to pursue this approach first.

Comment: Try all your runs on the same line of markup. The xml translation assumes an additional space as you have them.

Comment: @Andy not sure I understand what you mean by 'same line of markup'?

Comment: Run run run. These words are all on same line. Your markup is across 6+ lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply render transformation to adjust vertical position slightly:

```
<TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
</TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
<TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform Y="3" />
</TextBlock.RenderTransform>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I did think of this myself but the Translate offset amount is a bit arbitrary / guesswork and I'm not sure how it would react to Font Family and Font Size changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you look for something like [BaselineAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.baselinealignment?view=netcore-3.1)?

This would make your code look like this:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Run Foreground="Black" Text="XXX" BaselineAlignment="Center"/>
    <Run FontSize="50" Foreground="Green" Text="Δ" BaselineAlignment="Center" />
    <Run Foreground="Orange" Text="YYY" BaselineAlignment="Center" />
</TextBlock>
```

Update:

If you want to rotate the triangle, you can do it by adding a `<TextBlock>` insinde the textblock. So it looks like this:

```
<Run Foreground="Black" Text="XXX"  BaselineAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Magin="-12 0">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        <Run FontSize="50" Foreground="Green" Text="Δ" />
    </TextBlock>
    <Run Foreground="Orange" Text="YYY" BaselineAlignment="Center" />
</TextBlock>
```

It's a it messy, but it works:

And the result like this:

[image: Without rotation]

...and this, with rotation and margins

[image: With rotation and margin]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the idea, but this still leaves the gaps between the 'XXX' and 'YYY' and the special char.

Comment: @Cleve I didn't catch that initially. I have added yet another hack, adding `Margin="-12 0" to the textblock containing the triangle. Is that better?